# Menu background color when highlighted (clHightlightText doesn't work)

Tags: delphi, c++builder, vcl

I need to do some custom painting and when an item in the custom control is pressed or hovered over I want to display the highlighted item state.
PS. this is non-themed painting for Windows 2000 and high contrast (or when selected) on higher OS.

```cpp
if (State != rsNormal)
    {
    Canvas->Brush->Color = clHighlight ;
    Canvas->Font->Color  = clWhite ; // clHightlightText ;
    }
else
    {
    Canvas->Brush->Color = clBtnFace;
    Canvas->Font->Color  = clBtnText ;
    }
```

Current code, above, works perfectly for my need **but** `Font->Color` `clwhite` is of course what I can see is the case in Win2K, WinXP etc. but it is not a system color and I fear there may be situations where `clHighlight` may be a color that has not enough contrast with `clWhite`.

The [documentation](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Graphics_TColor.html) mentions: `clHightlightText`, which is basically what I need, yet my compiler C++ Builder 2009 doesn't know this system color and the fact that the documentation doesn't provide a link for it (different than the other colors) doesn't look good either.

How do I obtain a non-hard-coded value for the highlight text ?

Comment: The documentation you are linking to is old.  The current documentation is [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TColor).  Also see [Colors in the VCL](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Colors_in_the_VCL).

Comment: @RemyLebeau - I suppose I ended up with the older Help version because I did a search for `clHightlightText'.  So because of the typo I ended up finding the online version that has the typo as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clHighlightText` is the correct thing to use.  It is defined in the same `$(BCB)\include\vcl\Graphics.hpp` header file that defines *all* of the `cl...` color constants, including the other ones you are using:

```
static const TColor clHighlight = -16777203;
static const TColor clHighlightText = -16777202;
static const TColor clBtnFace = -16777201;
...
static const TColor clBtnText = -16777198;
...
static const TColor clWhite = 16777215;
```

These constants have been around for a LONG LONG time, going back to the early C++Builder versions.  Your version (CB2009) most definitely has them (the definitions above were copied from CB2009, in fact).

Comment: AH ... I see it now !!  Both online and system installed Help files have a TYPO ! **clHightlightText** should be `clHighlightText`  THAT is the problem !!  (A 't' too much ... bloody hard to spot as well ... for me at least)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out ... An educated guess

Cfr. the documentation of the rest of the system colors I tried the following:

```
TColor clHightlightText = TColor(clSystemColor | COLOR_HIGHLIGHTTEXT);
```

And this works nicely on Win2K, WinXP and Win7
Strange that both documentation and C++ Builder 2009 fail to do this properly and still wonder what the reason is ?  Lack of support in older OS ?  Anyway from Win2K and up it seems to work properly.

Comment: Although this will work, it is also redundant since the VCL already defines `clHighlightText` for you.  Look in `Graphics.hpp`, where all of the `cl...` constants are defined. `clHighlightText` is in there.

Comment: `clHightlightText` should be `clHighlightText`. That's why :)